# Java MessageDigest sha1 wrong result

Tags: java, cryptography

Example input: 0200302007 (a hex value)

```
byte[] utf8 = "0200302007".getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
messageDigest.update(utf8);
return messageDigest.digest();
```

SHA1 expected result is: `129DB11A3DEAFDAD52BC7CBEB20FD7947F31B7B6`

But the above code give results in:

```
ECC933969191424B4B67F3FA29C0E103471EC311
```

Why is that?

Comment: Actually, the code above gives `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d`. Where does the expected value come from?

Comment: The expected result is AAF4C61DDCC5E8A2DABEDE0F3B482CD9AEA9434D

Comment: Yes, that's what I get with this code. How did you arrive at your result?

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question, the salt should be hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the input value correctly:

```
byte[] utf8 = {0x2, 0x0, 0x30, 0x20, 0x7};
```